# This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: php, html, localhost

I have this assignment which in which I'm supposed to print out everything I put on the form. The form itself is working fine, but my php fil is not.

This is the php part of that file:

```
    if($_POST)
        {
            $firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
            $lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
            $areaCode = $_POST["areaCode"];
            $firstHalf = $_POST["firstHalf"];
            $secondHalf = $_POST["secondHalf"];
            $address1 = $_POST["address1"];
            $address2 = $_POST["address2"];
            $zipcode = $_POST["zipcode"];
            $state = $_POST["state"];

            echo "Name: <br/>";
            echo $firstName . " " . $lastName . "<br/>";
            echo "Phone number: " . "(" $areaCode . ")" . $firstHalf . "-" . $secondHalf . "<br/>";
            echo "Address: " . $address1 . ", " . $address2 . ", " . $state ", " . $zipcode . "<br/";
        }

    ?>
```

When I take the php part of the page, it loads fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you opening this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is in the last line

```
 echo "Address: " . $address1 . ", " . $address2 . ", " . $state ", " . $zipcode . "<br/";
```

You are missing a `.` after `$state`

```
 echo "Address: " . $address1 . ", " . $address2 . ", " . $state . ", " . $zipcode . "<br/";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem. There was the same mistake before $areaCode too that I just noticed.